# PySpark - Suggestion on Spark performance and tuning

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Looking for suggestions/guidance on PySpark.

For one of the business processes, we need to join and create a dataset which is 12.61 billion records. The challenges involves handling huge volume of data and processing time optimization. These records are aggregated at different levels and stored in HDFS as parquet format.

The initial processing time of 2hr 21 mins has been reduced to 1hr 10mins by performing optimizing using spark & hadoop features in several iterations, trying various combinations of shuffle partitions, cores, cache. (listed the details at the end)

Now per latest changes, we have added 300+ million records to the processing and see that there is significant drop in performance. The process now executes anywhere between 2hr 30 mins to 3 hrs.

Need your suggestion, ideas on what can be done to achieve the goal of executing under 1 hr timeline.

Additional Details:

- Tech Stack used: PySpark (Connecting to Cloudera for Spark)
- Input data is in HDFS and as well as aggregated results are written back to HDFS as well.
- Number of Executors: 8
- Executor Memory: 10G
- Executor Cores: 5
- Driver Memory: 10G

We have already implemented the following in the code.

- Broadcast join at appropriate place (Used for smaller dataset)
- Cache used for dataframe/files which are repeatedly used
- All the dataframe absolutely using the columns which are required
- Tried several shuffle partitions (default 200), 100, 300, 400. 300 seems to be good for this volume of data.
- Tried repartition the dataframe, but was not helpful.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour], [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [ask]. Unfortunately, this question falls under opinion based and will be closed/downvoted.